# Groupby by a column and unique in another column

Tags: python, pandas

My df is as follows:

```
col1   col2 
1      A
1      B
1      A
2      C
3      D
```

What i am trying to achieve is as follows:

```
col1   col2 
 1      A          
 1      B
 2      C
 3      D
```

My requirement is i have to find the unique entries in col2 based on groupby in col1. I am newbie to python and pandas i tried a lot but cant find the solution. Please share your ideas.

What i have tried:(sample code)

```
 df = pd.read_csv('input' + '/' +file_name)
    def func2(df):        
        CODE4 = df['col2'].unique() 
            result.append(pd.Series([code[0],code1[0],code2[0],code3[0],CODE4[0]],index=headers))
            return df

         df  = df.groupby(['col1']).apply(func2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the unique entries in col2 based on groupby in col1. 
This is equivalent to drop row if both col1 and col2 values are duplicated:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'])
```

Comment: Thanks. Smart solution.